# sql server performance optimization on a small fix table

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Now I have a small table [dbo].[Model], it includes two columns:id(int) and model(nvarchar(48)).

```
create table Model
(
    id int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
    model nvarchar(48)
)
```

There are about two thousand of records in the table and usually needn't to insert a new record unless a new model is found.

Now I have another table Attribute

```
create table Attribute
(
     id bigint primary key identity(1,1) not null,
     typeid int not null,--foreign key from another table
     modelid int not null,--foreign key from [Model] table
     attr nvarchar(max)
)
```

Now I should store millions of rows of data into the [Attribute] table, first I should get the model id from [Model] table, due to the [Model] table is small, if I use select statement frequently to get the model id, I don't think it's a good idea because it includes multiply duplicate select.

I think I can use only one select statement to generate data like map, when I get a model, I needn't select any more, if it already exists in the map data, use it directly, otherwise, insert a new record into the [Model] table.

Above solution is my guess, I'm not familiar with sql server or it's performance optimization. what I should do to solve the problem or which kind of knowledge should I learn?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

When fishing for a record (whether or not it exists), the compactness of the first table will help.  Searching for a record among a few thousand is much better than doing the same search among millions of records.

Now on the flip side, the performance of the second table will invariably be slow, as having that nvarchar(max) with its indeterminate size will work against most efforts to optimize searches.  Some records will have short strings, others long ones.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to select data only once from the first table and store them into some data struct.